# Azure Active Directory, Multiple Organizations and Tenants

Tags: active-directory, domain, entra-id, microsoft-365

When working with Azure Active Directory, does the product have a way to support multiple directories under a single tenant?

I am trying to use this example on a company that is a parent company of 3 subsidiaries. Each of the three companies are a brand of the parent company, but each company has its own unique brand as well. I only want there to be 1 tenant, not 2 or 3, and if there is a way to have multiple directories under a single tenant.

The only options I seemed to uncover were:

1. Add all the domains in a single directory and tenant. They can freely communicate and authenticate. I could use the "Company Name" field and other attributes to reflect which company a user or resource is for. The only problem I found is that certain organization level attributes like the company portal, will show the parent company for each of the three companies.
2. Put the directories and domains in a separate tenant for each company/organization. I didn't like this solution because federating and signing into a computer from another tenant had limitations that I did not want, although there is collaboration and guest user capability. An example would be a user signing into a different org Azure AD account with the same PC.

I thought I read a way where I could have every org in the same tenant, but different directories

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean Azure AD for Office 365 and syncing your on premises AD for each company to a single Azure AD/Office 365 tenant. If that's correct then yes, it is possible.

This document explains the supported, and unsupported, topologies for Azure AD Connect:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-topologies

Comment: No. These are organizations with no on-premises solutions.